# Как вывести содержимое из одного файла в стандартный поток вывода , использую системные выводы и функции стандартной библиотеки языка С?

Tags: c++, linux, c

Что такое стандартные потоки. Как вывести содержимое файла в файл, используя готовую программу (не меняя самой программы) данного задания.

Comment: [man cat](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cat)?

Answer (score 0):

Стандартные потоки
stdin ввод
stdout вывод
stderr поток ошибок
Для управления потоками используются (> < | >> << )
Для вывода из одного файла в другой My_file > new_file